# What is the contents of the register? MIPS32 assembly

Tags: memory, assembly, model, mips

I'm currently learning how assembly works and suppose the memory model:

```
Label    Content     Address
 x:         3        0x0000
 y:         7        0x0001
 z:         2        0x0002
point:     0x00      0x0003
           0x00      0x0004
           0x00      0x0005
           0x07      0x0006
array:      'H'      0x0007
            'I'      0x0008
            '\n'     0x0009
            '\0'     0x000A
main: lw $t0, array  0x000B
            -        0x000C
      la $t1, point  0x000D
```

In the main program, would the contents of `$t0` be `"HI"` or `'H''I''\n''\0'` ?

and if I were to load the address of point into $t1, does that mean it loads the address of `0x0003`, `0x0004`, `0x0005`, `0x000` into $t1? For the pointer `point`, I see the it's pointing to the address of `0x007`, so does that mean it points to the beginning of the array?

I just need clarification.

Comment: Can't you just run it and print the values to find out?

Comment: `lw` from address 7 would most likely fail since the address isn't word-aligned. But as the previous commenter said, just download SPIM or MARS and run your program and find out for yourself.